# How to set value of ng-model attribute based on value from $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$scope.fieldsets =
    [
        {
        fields:
            [
                {
                    label: 'What would you call your idea?',
                    name: 'name',
                    key: 'entry.810220554',
                    type: 'text',
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Bild',
                    type: 'file',
                    key: 'entry.810220554',
                    required: false
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

It generates a bunch of fields, like this:
(this is simplified)

```
   <input
     type="{{field.type}}" 
     name="{{field.key}}"  
     id="{{field.name}}" 
     ng-required="field.required"
```

/>

Currently, I post the values using http-post and a html-form. I would like to use angular $http.post instead. Therefore i would like to bind the  the value connected to the key-key in the array. So it posts with the same key-values as it does when I post it in html with the name-attribute.

```
                   <input
                        ng-switch-default
                        type="{{field.type}}" 
                        name="{{field.key}}"  
                        id="{{field.name}}" 
                        ng-required="field.required"
                        ng-model="{{field.key}}"
                    />
```

but this generates an error. I also tried `ng-model="field.key"`the problem with this is that the input is populated with the value entry.810220554, I want `ng-model=entry.810220554`

Comment: `ng-model` will also bind the value of the input, you have the correct syntax at `ng-model="field.key"`

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-model="entry[field.key]"`, if the value of `field.key` is indeed a key in the `entry` hash.

Comment: I don't think one can change bindings dynamically i think. In your example it may create watch on the first value of `field.key` maybe.

Comment: You are both right, I did not notice that `entry.` is in the key value. The `[field.key]` is nice.